# Random Letter Generator

Tags: javascript, random

I'm a total newb here learning how to code :)
Hoping someone can shed some light on the following.

I'm writing some code in JavaScript to generate a random mix of 6 letters from the alphabet using a Math.random method and a for-loop.

I can get this to work when I write the code 'Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)' directly into the array index however when I assign it to a variable and use that as the index instead, I end up with a 'random' letter that's duplicated 6 times.

Is it possible to assign a random value (using the Math.random method) to a variable and have it execute each time it goes through the loop?
Thanks in advance!

**This is the code that works:**

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var randomString = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
randomString += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];

console.log(randomString);
}
```

Output code example: xuhmwg

**This code ends up with duplicated letters:**

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var randomString = "";
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
randomString += alphabet[randomNumber];

console.log(randomString);
}
```

Output code example: dddddd

Comment: put this `var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);` inside the loop before `randomString += alphabet[randomNumber];`

Comment: Run the code with a debugger to see what's happening. Simply put, assigning a value to a variable assigns it once. Change it to `var randomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);` and use `randomString += alphabet[randomNumber()];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks all, Kenny's suggestion of adding it in the loop before randomString worked a charm!

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would do it.

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var randomString = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
randomString += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
console.log(randomString);
}
```